# How can this postgresql query return as table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-functions

I am trying to call modules which in specific course but it returns as error: **more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression**

**Query:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION course_modules(_courseID integer)

RETURNS SETOF modules AS

$$

BEGIN   

RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM modules WHERE mod_id =(SELECT module_id from coursemodules WHERE course_id = _courseID);

END

 $$

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

**coursemodule table**

```
 CREATE TABLE coursemodules(
 course_id integer references courses (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
 module_id integer references modules (mod_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
 );
```

**Modules Table**

```
 CREATE TABLE modules(
 documents text   NOT NULL,
 mod_id serial primary key,
 content text   NOT NULL,
 title varchar(50)  NOT NULL
 );
```

**Course Table**

```
 CREATE TABLE courses(
 finishDate Date,
 description text  NOT NULL,
 duration varchar(50)   NOT NULL,
 startDate Date,
 id serial primary key,
 courseName varchar(50)   NOT NULL
 );
```

Comment: If you run `SELECT course_id, COUNT(*) FROM coursemodules GROUP BY course_id` you'll see the rows where `course_id` is repeated.

Comment: I note that `course_id` is not declared the primary-key of the `coursemodules` table, nor are there any `UNIQUE` constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no restriction in the coursemodule table that a course could only have one module. Because of that the `SELECT module_id from coursemodules WHERE course_id = _courseID` subquery could return multiple lines.

If you change `mod_id = (SELECT module_id from coursemodules WHERE course_id = _courseID)`

to

`mod_id IN (SELECT module_id from coursemodules WHERE course_id = _courseID)`.

It should work. Otherwise you have to add constraints to the coursemodule table.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple SQL syntax error.  You're using

```
WHERE mod_id =
```

But you may have more than one row returning from the subquery. User IN:

```
WHERE mod_id IN
```